# How can I persist tpm keys on disk using .NET and Tpm2Lib?

Tags: .net, tpm, key-management

Instead use the tpm limited non-volatile memory, I want to persist a generated tpm key on my hard disk. What is the best way to this?

I'm using the Tpm2Lib to .NET from Microsoft, and I'm implementing that solution at linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't persist them on disk but recreate them on demand with exactly the same key template.
If you call TPM2_CreatePrimary with the same key template (and the same internal seed) you would recreate exactly the same key.

Comment: Hi @watts. How can I create the same key template? I've been testing with TSS.MSR CPP's sample code. However, given the same template. I always have different keys created. I suspect I have to set the `unique` parameter of the TPMT_PUBLIC structure to a constant value. But even after doing so. I still get different keys.